# symfony 2 cant save to database correctly

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, save

To be short
my entity have this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Classes", inversedBy="")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="class_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $class;
```

i have no inverse relation, because i don't need it.
and i try to do this:

```
    $class = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TomasRClassBundle:Classes')->find($_POST['fighter']['class']);
                $item = new Fighter();
                $item->setName($_POST['fighter']['name']);
                $item->setClass($class);
//if i var_dump here $item->getClass(), its there, class where set correctly
                $item->setBelongsTo(1);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($item);
                $em->flush();
```

and after that in database, in class_id i have null.. however if I edit it with form, this is form field:

```
$builder->add('class', 'entity', array('class' => 'TomasRClassBundle:Classes','property' => 'name'));
```

and after i submit the form i do:

```
$item = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TomasRClassBundle:Fighter')->find($id);
        $type = new FighterForm();

        $form = $this->createForm($type, $item);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($item);
            $em->flush();

            //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_fighter_list'));
        }
```

and now the class_id field in db is set correctly.

i could hard code my solution, but i wanna know what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, i know it might be a bit hard to read, sorry for that :)

Comment: When you save it does it show any error?

Comment: Furthermore, if you do not have a inversedBy you should not write it in `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Classes", inversedBy="")`

Comment: nop, no errors,@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Classes") did not helped

Comment: Have you debug your validation? Maybe it never pass the validation to persist the new item. You can var_dump something inside `if` clause of validation to make sure if it pass it

Comment: Also what is `Fighter` and `FighterForm` which you defined as type?

Comment: it passis i vardumped item just before persisting it.. item has class i vardumped it after flush item has class and there, but no class in database, it just does not set class_id..

Comment: its not a form's problem, i wanna do simple stuff just create new item, add some info to it, set class to it (i find class in database by id) and save it.

Comment: Your app is in development mode, correct? I.e. you are pointing to app_dev.php? Unless you explicitly edited your .htaccess file to do this, it's not. I've just never heard of symfony2 silencing errors in a development environment. If your data is not being saved, there is an error of some sort.

Comment: yes its dev, but if it is some error don't u think that it would be no data saved? because i flush it in single line.. i am kinda interested myself what is wrong thats why i wrote here p.s. its not my first symfony2 project

Comment: Can I dump what do you have in `FighterForm`; I guess the type you created might not add the `class_id` (base on [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-creating-form-classes] )

Comment: javad if i do it with form it saves all, problem is once i create a new object and i add info to it manually.